# google maps doesnt update in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-map

I have google maps model ng-map, when i write location it doesnt show that place, but if we inspect then it puts in `center="London"` that location

```
    <div class="form-group move-down">
        <label for="Autocomplete">Generic Autocomplete</label>
            <input ng-model="result1" type="text" id="Autocomplete" class="form-control" ng-autocomplete="result1" details="details1" options="options1"/>
    </div>


    <map style="display:block;height:300px" center="{{result1}}" zoom="15" />
```

Comment: `center` needs an object that has a lat and long value, it doesn't work by simply entering a city name

Comment: You'll need to use the Geocoding API to transform an address to a set of geographical coordinates: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: but the interesting part is that if i write in template `center="London"` or the coordinates it shows the location